# How can I set a value on my page (not form) for jQuery to check?

Tags: jquery

I need to identify my pages with something that can be picked up by:

```
function refreshGrid(entity) {
    var contentID = $('#ContentID').val();
```

So I need some element that has a value or something that I can check in my external script. I tried `<input id="ContentID" type="hidden" value="01">` but not inside a form. It always seem to set itself to "00" and I think probably it is not a good idea to use  when not inside a form.

Is there some other way I could place a value inside an element on a page that I could check. I just need something where I could put codes such as "00" or "01" or "02" etc.  I would also like to do this the "correct" way so I'd not like to use a form.

Comment: You can't use #contentID in several places on your page because it's an ID -- it's meant to be unique, because of this jQuery will loop through the document, find the first element with the id of contentID, and grab it's value and return it. Use classes and loop through them to find the element that you want, or generate dynamically specific markup in the ID area.

Comment: There should be no problem with the hidden input (even if not inside a form), noting that as always if you try to get the value from JS (with or without jQuery) the element will not be found unless the browser has already parsed it. That is, the JS script has to be included _after_ the field and/or make use of a document.ready or onload handler.

Comment: maybe you have more than two element with same id's...
It would be helpful if you explain exactly where the problem is occurring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not particularly elegant, but it sounds like a hidden `<span>` will suffice.

```
<span id="ContentID" style="display: none;">01</span>
```

and

```
function refreshGrid(entity) {
    var contentID = $('#ContentID').text();
```

Comment: D'oh. I was just about the post the same thing. I need to type faster... :)

Comment: I've no problem with using a span, but why would a span work where an input doesn't?

Comment: I think it mst be $('#foo') instead of $('#ContentId')

Answer (score 1):

maybe you forgot using jQuery's `.ready()` and loaded your script before the DOM.

works here: http://jsfiddle.net/G4h8h/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function refreshGrid(entity) {
        var contentID = $('#contentID').val();
        alert(contentID);
    }
    refreshGrid('something');
});​
```

also, check your console once in a while. JS suspends further scripts from running when it spots errors (the fatal ones)..

Answer (score 1):

You might want to store your data in either a `meta` tag or a `data` attribute on a container tag. This will keep arbitrary application data out of places it might be confused with content.

```
$('<meta option="foo" value="bar"').appendTo('head');
var foo = $('meta[option="foo"]').val();
```

Or:

```
$('body').attr('data-foo', 'bar');
var foo = $('body').attr('data-foo');
```

Comment: I like this idea. I just want to hardcode this ID. I do have <div id="actionList" > which contains all of the buttons. Could I hardcode this as a data attribute for the DIV? How could I check it with jQuery?

Comment: You sure could. See the second example I give--just replace the `body` selector with one that points to your `div` and you should be golden!